# The unreasonable effectiveness of physical exercise for post graduate student?

Tags: health

I am a graduate student who is currently doing a lot of research works. I understand that academia is a stressful place and it is normal to feel unmotivated and depressed. Recently, I have incorporate a 25 minutes uphill jogging into my daily schedule (an advice from a recent PHD graduate). Although, this reduce the amount of work I can do everyday but all of my stress, sadness and insomnia disappear magically.

I do not understand why such simple exercise could elevate my mood so much despite the fact that I still cannot solve my research problem. Is there really any reasonable explanation for this phenomenon ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: https://www.apa.org/topics/exercise-fitness/stress

Comment: I don't think this is particular to graduate students, exercise generally can help anyone who's stressed.

Comment: This is a question about medical science, not academia.

Answer (score 1):

Not only for grad students, but for people in general, it has been well established that exercising causes your brain to release endorphines that trigger a positive feeling and help with reducing stress. See [here](https://www.webmd.com/depression/guide/exercise-depression) for example.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, when including links in Stack Exchange answers it's considered good practice to give a summary of what the link contains. This helps the answer to be complete even if the link dies in the future.